# Codility FrogJmp strange Java score

Tags: java, time-complexity

So I decided to try out [Codility](https://codility.com/). The first task - [FrogJmp](https://codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/frog_jmp) was ridiculous easy, however to my surprise I scored 44%. Solution, even if correct was obviously unacceptable in terms of performance.

Original solution:

```
public int solution2(int X, int Y, int D) {
    return (int) Math.ceil((float)(Y -X)/D);
}
```

So I decided to try it with different code, without floating point arithmetic.

```
public int solution(int X, int Y, int D) {
    int diff = Y - X;
    if (diff % D == 0)
        return diff /D; 
    else
        return diff/D + 1;

}
```

This time I got 100%. So I wanted to check the performance myself and wrote simple test:

```
class Solution {


    public int solution(int X, int Y, int D) {
        int diff = Y - X;
        if (diff % D == 0)
            return diff /D; 
        else
            return diff/D + 1;

    }

    public int solution2(int X, int Y, int D) {
        return (int) Math.ceil((float)(Y -X)/D);
    }


    private static Random ran = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    public static int getRandom(int a, int b){
        return ran.nextInt(b - a + 1) + a; 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int size = 1000_000;
        int max = 1000_000_000;

        int[] xs = new int[size];
        int[] ys = new int[size];
        int[] ds = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int y = getRandom(1, max);
            int x = getRandom(1, y);
            int d = getRandom(1, max);
            xs[i] = x;
            ys[i] = y;
            ds[i] = d;
        }

        long start = System.nanoTime();

        Solution sol = new Solution();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sol.solution2(xs[i], ys[i], ds[i]);
        }

        long diff = System.nanoTime() - start;

        System.out.println("took: " + diff/1000000 + "ms");
    }
}
```

To my surprise, on my machine the solution 1 takes on average 13ms and solution 2 (the one reported as absolutely ineffective) 10 ms.

What am I missing?

Maybe it has to do something with expected time and space complexity of the tasks.

> expected worst-case time complexity is O(1); expected worst-case space
>   complexity is O(1).

Does not solution 2 have constant time & space complexity?

Also I cannot make sense of this results report for 44% solution:

[image]

What does it mean??

Comment: Coding micro-benchmarks, especially in Java, is an extremely hard task. I wouldn't bother with this. What matters is readability and maintainability. 99% of programs must not be as fast as possible. They must be fast enough.

Comment: @JB I know this as I know that solution 2 is preferable in terms of code readability. But I am bothered by that score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both solutions have O(1) time complexity. The problem is that the first solution is returning wrong answers. The performance tests test the answer as well as the time. Your solution failed probably because of precision issues with the use of floats.

For x = 1, y = 1000000000, d = 1, your first solution gives 1000000000 as an answer, and the second gives 
999999999. Changing from `(float)` to `(double)` corrects this result.

In these algorithm tests, it's usually a good idea to avoid floating point arithmetic as much as possible to make it easier to get the exact answers for all cases.

Comment: Omg, of course! I was so baffled by "Correctness 100%, Performance 0%" that I did not even bother thinking about this. So can it be said that the test result is stating  it wrongly? It is not performance issue but wrong answers for some inputs.

Comment: To test performance they need to use large inputs, but these are the same inputs that cause precision issues, so it's not clear if these tests should be under 'performance' or 'correctness' headings. If there was a performance problem it would say something else like 'time limit exceeded' instead of 'wrong answer'.

Answer (score 4):

100/100 solution in C# I just

```
using System;    
class Solution {
    public int solution(int X, int Y, int D) {        
        return ((Y - X) + D - 1)/D;        
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer this solution, its easier and you dont have to convert to float.

Answer (score 4):

Solution in Java 100/100 and O(1) time complexity.

```
public int solution(int X, int Y, int D) {
    return Double.valueOf(Math.ceil((Y - X) / (double) D)).intValue();
}
```

Comment: isnt this returning double?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch No, it doesn't. At the end of the line you can see, that the `intValue()` method is called.

Answer (score 2):

Solution in Java 100/100 and O(1) time complexity:

```
public int solution(int X, int Y, int D) {
    int diff = Y - X;
    int count = diff / D;
    if (diff % D > 0) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**OBJECTIVE-C SOLUTION O(1)**

**Results given by Codility**

Task Score: 100%
Correctness: 100%
Performance: 100%

**Time Complexity**

The worst case time complexity is O(1)

[Xcode Solution Here](https://github.com/jmanuelmosso/CSWarmingInterview/blob/master/CSWarmingInterview/CodilityChallenges/TimeComplexity/FrogJmp.m)

```
+(int)solution:(int)x y:(int)y d:(int)d {

    /******** Algorithm Explanation  ********/

    // FACTS
    //      I realized that the formula:    [x+(n*d)] >= y    satisfies the required frog jumps
    //      then, the formula to find the 'n' required jumps is the following:
    //      n = (y-x)/d

    // STEP 1
    //     Implement the formula in code
    //     Be careful dealing with the floating point, it should be double
    //     use the function 'ceil' as a resource to round to the next integer.

    double n = ((double)y - (double)x) / (double)d; // O(1)
    n = ceil(n);
    return (int)n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JS Solution

Task Score: 100%
Correctness: 100%
Performance: 100%

```
function solution(X, Y, D) {
    return Math.ceil((Y - X) / D);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution in C#

```
double result = (Y - X) / (D * 1.0);
return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int solution(int X, int Y, int D) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8


       return (int)Math.round((Y-X)/(double)D);

    }
```

This will also fetch 100%

Answer (score 1):

Tried this one for 100/100

```
public static int frogJmp(int X, int Y, int D) {
    return (int) Math.ceil( (Y-X) / (double)D );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple O(1) solution in Java:

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int X, int Y, int D) {
        return (Y-X) % D == 0 ? (Y-X) / D : (Y-X) / D + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Count minimal number of jumps from position X to Y.

```
public int solution(int X, int Y, int D) {
 if (X == Y)
  return 0;
 else if ((Y - X) % D == 0)
  return ((Y - X) / D);
 else
  return ((Y - X) / D) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should pay attention to divisor which can not be 0 in your case "`diff / D`", **`D`** can not be **`0`**.

Second, in your case "`diff = Y - X`", if ( diff <= 0 ) then you don't to jump anymore.

Comment: According to the problem description, D >= 1 and Y >= X. The correct response if these constraints are violated is not given or checked for.

Answer (score 0):

Frogjump solution in C

```
int solution(int X, int Y, int D) {
        // write your code in C90
        int r=0;

        if(Y>X)
        {   
            r=(Y-X)/D;
            if((X+(r*D)) < Y) r++;
        }

        return r;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int solution(int X, int Y, int D) {
    // write your code in C# 6.0 with .NET 4.5 (Mono)
    double divAll = (Y-X) / (D * 1.0);
    double finalRes = (Y-X) % (D * 1.0) > 0 ? (divAll + 1) : divAll;

    return (int) finalRes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 100% / 100% solution

```
public int solution(int X, int Y, int D) {
    double d = D;
    return (int) Math.ceil( (Y-X) / d );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved it with perfect score, So this is my answer (java):

```
static int solution(int X, int Y, int D){

    double count=((double)Y-(double)X)/(double) D;

    return (int)Math.ceil(count);
 }
```

For the first time i thought it could be rdone by using "While loops" but i got zero performance..

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is my simple code with detected time complexity of O(1) in Codility.

public int solution(int X, int Y, int D) {
        int dev = (Y - X) % D;
        if (X == Y)
            return 0;
        else if (dev == 0)
            return (Y - X) / D;
        else
            return ((Y - X) / D) + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution 100% in JS

```
function solution(X, Y, D) {
  const distance = Y - X;
  if (distance % D === 0) {
    return Math.round(distance/D);
  } 
  return Math.floor(distance/D +1);
}
```